# Phpmailer doesn't pick up the WordPress site domain

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer, postfix-mta

How do shared hosting providers make Phpmailer pick up the site domain when using Postfix?
My smtp.mailfrom (as seen in message source) has vm1234.provider.tld instead of mydomain.tld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are doing is what I would expect a shared hosting provider to do, but In PHPMailer code, set the `Sender` property to override the default envelope sender.

Comment: Ok, but what if PHPMailer is controlled by WordPress? And I have several Linux users running WordPress apps.

Comment: I’d recommend asking WP devs, or creating/using a plugin that gives you control over it. It’s not up to PHPMailer or your hosting provider.